# internal compiler error

Tags: linux, compile

I am getting this message:

`internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs> for instructions.`

for every compilation that takes longer (ie: linux kernel, kde sources etc.)

I've tried other OS (at that moment I was on Fedora 12, now on Debian; was a Suse also) and it didn't work.
I've tried replacing my hard disk, since it needed an upgrade either ways - that didn't work either.
I assumed that it's the RAM fault - tested them with memtest and it says they are fine.

Does anyone know what else I can do in order to figure out where the problem is?

Comment: it's not a hardware error, and I don't have the same problem, so it must be a problem between computer and chair :P do you use any abnormal compiler flags? Is it 32 or 64 bit? Can you do other computationally intense things? (memtest doesn't really test your processor) can you try getting a backtrace from gcc?

Comment: there's no weird compiler flags, even if I use the default settings, I get the same behaviour. Err, how do you get a backtrace from gcc, besides what I've already posted? ;-)

Comment: attach gdb to gcc and then `run` then it'll crash eventually and you'll get told at what address and stuff, then just type `backtrace` and it should tell you where it crashed.

Comment: here's one: http://pastebin.com/hjVFcrtN ... though I am pretty sure the gcc guys will tell me that this is a hardware issue .. been there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the last time i had this error: ram was defect.

Comment: This was the problem, I just acquired a new memory dimm and the problem is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try checking out your processor's heat levels - it could be that things are overheating leading to errors while the CPU is under heavy load.

Comment: Yea, memtest usually heats up the CPU pretty well though.. course, no computations really in memtest.

Comment: Seems to be comfortable at around 45-46 degrees Celsius, which seems okish, given the fact that it is an Athlon XP 64